Exact/general formula for DX7 phases
According to Beauchamp (1992), the DX7 implements a peculiar variation of FM, with the phases of the carrier and modulator not being consistently sine or cosine, but rather based on his limited sampling of the combinations:

Since a lot more work has been put into reverse engineering the DX7 in the meantime, including some chip decaps, has anyone figured out the exact formula the DX7 uses in general to pick those phases? (Somewhat of a side question: is it just an unintentional artifact of some implementation detail, or does it look like it might have had a musical reason?)
N.B. Since the phases are 0 or pi, it's reading the same sine table, which was a ROM on the DX7 storing just a quarter period, and just flipping the sign bit in different orders. I guess that's part of the reason. But they could have perhaps kept a consistent phase, so that's probably not the whole story. (I suppose pi/2 [i.e. cosine] phases might have been easy to generate too, but more objectionable due to 'pops'?)
Ah, the table above has the columns in 'swizzled' order. Past that, it seem apparent that phi_c is 0 for f_c = 1 and becomes pi for f_c = 2. But the choice for phi_m does not seem based just on f_m, e.g. it's pi for 1:1 but 0 for 2:1. Choosing phi_m 0 for f_m = 2 makes some sense because the opposite choice will give a 'thin' shape instead of converging to a square-ish shape as the modulation is (initially) increased from zero. I suppose that if they decided they needed to do some sign flips for whatever reason, they might have chosen 1:2 to have phi_m 0 for that reason.

phi_c flips the phase of the whole waveform, so it doesn't affect the sound of the waveform, only how the waveform interacts with other waveforms. For 1:2, phi_m = 0 indeed generates a waveform closer to a square wave, which means higher RMS: almost 7dB more than phi_m = π at I=1. But I don't think that's the only reason, there are probably some aesthetic ones.

@user1079505: BTW, I've not been able to find this published, so I've worked out how the power varies with the modulation index. For a carrier to modulator frequency ratio of nf : 2f (with n integer), the square of the power is 1/2 - 1/2 J(-n, 2K), where J is the Bessel function (of order -n in this case) and K is the modulation index. The math is a bit hairy. This is for the sin-sin (0 phase) case. I fairly sure it also changes with the phase[s].
